# Ability to transfer ownership of "no longer mantainable" own questions to other interested owners, in order to keep them correct and reactive

Tags: feature-request, unaccepted-answer, abandoned-questions

A few times it happened to me that after having posted a technical question on a complicate thing I was working on, I had to switch to a completely different task, slowly and unconsciously letting the former thing and the related SO question move to the very back of my mind to a point where after many years I would be completely incapable of contributing to it in any way (i.e. choosing a right answer, upvoting/downvoting some others, answering to comments).

In all of those cases, when stumbling again on those questions randomly (perhaps after having been notified for a new answer), I would tell myself that I'd come back to it, re-examine everything from the bottom up, and give the  appropriate contribute to it, but the fact is, no matter how hard I want that, since my time/energy is limited (I finally understood that), I will never actually return to it anymore, unless I start working on the project that originated the question again. Not saying that this is not possible, but could happen so late in the future that it will just cause another question to be asked and mine quoted as an old one.

In order to fix this, I propose  that the owner of the question may decide to put the question in a "new owner needed" status, so to allow the question to come back to life again by the means of a new owner and serve the community again properly. This will also allow right-answerers to get the deserved credit, and new owners will take credit from question upvotes/downvotes.

It's not that points and the green checkmark are everything, of course, but we all know how effective they are at triggerring corrections to answers (when those are not correctly balanced, or when wrong one is marked right) and at triggering further constructive debate... This in turn will keep questions more up to date and prevent new duplicate questions to be created ("because that old question seems wrong or obsolete...").

**UPDATE, end line:**

In the end it's not about points and checkmarks. It's only about optimizing this place by making it more consistent and tidier. And I think it's great when this can be done just by means of content owners' self-optimization.

---

What do you think? Sorry if it's a bit verbose, I tried to express it in my best English. Feel free to edit it if you think you can make it sound better ;)

Comment: As long as the question has answers and votes it has served the community and will continue still. Sure it might not have a green check mark but that is not the mark of good content.

Comment: But I want to be able to let right answerer get credit, and let the question feel completed so that when someone else comes to it, they could say that accepted answer is not the right one, thus sparkling an additional reconsideration by the new owner... meaning the question will stay more efficently up to date and obsolescence-caused duplicates could be avoided...

Comment: The community will give credit where credit is due. 15 points is not a major  turning point in an SO career. Proper content will also acquire upvotes from other users. Creating good content is all SO users should be aspiring to do. Points are secondary

Comment: @jj_ an accept mark means NOTHING, except "the OP wanted to click on that mark". If there's a +1 answer with the checkmark, and a +20 answer without, I might not even LOOK at the accepted one...

Comment: My issues are not with points themselves. But with the absence of a right answer caused of the absence of an "actively mantaining owner" which many times just makes the question to be seen as dead and "non reactive" to new contributions in some sort of way... thus new duplicates questions will be created asking for up to date solutions...

Comment: I'm wondering how meta this will become if I never accept an answer...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're asking for a feature that we already have. Its called a [community wiki.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

> Community wiki posts work by partly transferring ownership of the post
>   from the original author to the community. They make the post easier
>   to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not
>   contribute to any user's reputation.

Comment: That sounds perfect but I think the OP of this question might have an issue with "_do not contribute to any user's reputation._"

Comment: @Matt "You can't always get what we want, but if you try sometime you might find you get what you need..."

Comment: My issues are not with points themselves. But with the absence of a right answer, caused by the absence of an "actively mantaining owner" which many times just makes the question to be seen as dead and "non reactive" to new contributions  in some sort of way...  thus new duplicates questions will be created asking for up to date solutions...

Comment: This is where I begin my slow clap.... for the song comment

Comment: @jj_ community wikis that the community find particularly helpful usually get curated by the community.  If they aren't really that useful there's no issue with them falling into obscurity.

Comment: This is not the same feature. The fact itself that the conversion into a CW is every time subject to the moderators' opinion (as I supposed) on wheter the unabilty of the OP to curate their own post represents a valid enough reason for that, is completely against the self-managed, question optimization purpose of my proposal. This is not about nitpicking on points and checkmarks. It's about optimizing this place by making it more consistent, complete, and tidier. And I think it's great you could get this for free, only thanks to a self-managed question re-routing.

Answer (score 1):

## I don't see how changing the owner would affect the content.

The content of course being the important thing (more so than the credit and reputation).

Know that I can understand where you are coming from. However I think you are reading too much into this. Assuming that the question is good and on-topic it will attract the right attention on its own. Similarly if the answers are also high caliber then the community will give all deserving parties the attention and reputation they deserve.

I have seen plenty of great questions abandoned by their original OP but they still got many upvotes.

As long as the question has answers and votes it has served the community and will continue still. Sure it might not have a green check mark but that is not the mark of good content.

Content can become stale and if better questions come along hopefully someone looks for the correct duplicate and set the targets appropriately. In most cases duplicates are good. Just more pointers helping people get to the right content like breadcrumbs.

Comment: If you change fron an unactive owner to an active one then it does affect the content. Imagine taking the control of some questions which have a wrong answer marked as correct. Then you would check the correct one. Many people would be instantly notified. There would be a more constant up-to-date debate. Just saying that resulting notifications from actively mantaining a question alive pushes more people to give their contribute.

Comment: @jj_ If the wrong answer was marked correct then I would expect downvotes or other answers with more upvotes or comments. The green check mark I have seen helps the OP. Upvotes and comments drive the value of the content. I have seen many of those question where the marked answer is not the best answer. To each there own though. This is a large community with lots of view points.